# Is there a receive shadow only in a-frame

Tags: render, aframe, shadow

I'm trying to create a plane that will receive a shadow but will be invisible to the camera in order to make a 3d model look like floating

tried to make material transparent

```
     <!-- this is the shadow system -->
    <a-entity light="type: ambient; intensity: 0.5;"></a-entity>
     <a-entity light="type: directional;
               castShadow: true;
               intensity: 1;
               shadowCameraVisible: true;"
        position="0 0 5"></a-entity>
    <a-assets>

        <!-- the models -->
        <a-asset-item id="animated-asset" src="https://artshirtsonline.com/shanatova/models/test_lines.gltf"  ></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

        <a-marker id='animated-marker' type='pattern' preset='custom' url='https://artshirtsonline.com/shanatova/markers/pattern-qrcode2.patt'>

                   <a-entity animation-mixer="loop: repeat" gltf-model='#animated-asset' 
            scale="1 1 1"
            shadow="cast: true"
            rotation="-90 0 0"></a-entity>

        <a-circle id="ground" radius="7" rotation="-90 0 0" position="0 -2 0" shadow="receive: true"  ></a-circle>
    </a-marker>

    <a-entity camera ></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
```

I expect to get a shadow only on a surface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible, but you need to do a bit of threejs programming to make it work.

Here is an example of shadow casting the normal way:
https://glitch.com/~shadow-cast-basic.

note that you must set the light to cast shadows, and you must place a shadow component 
on the shadow caster and receiver. You adjust the quality of the shadow in the scene entity.
`<a-scene shadow="type: pcfsoft">`

The shadow is clearly visible, but plane is not transparent.

To achieve the desired effect( visible shadow with transparent object), you must use the THREEjs shadow material.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial

Aframe does not provide access to this directly, but you can make a custom component that creates the material for you. Here is an example of that.
https://glitch.com/~shadow-material

Comment: OMG that was so simple! Thank you so much Thomas!! and thank you ShadowMaterial

Comment: @Adam It'd be appreciated if you mark the anwser :)
I've dug deep in shadowMaps, also didn't realize it would be so simple :)

Comment: If you feel the anwser is the best solution to your problem, you can click the checkmark beside the anwser (citing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: Welcome to Answer Overflow, where the only price you have to pay is gratitude (ie playing by the rules). Thanks for your efforts. One day, you too, will be hoping that absolute beginners figure out how to thank you for your efforts. :D

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a few months ago for an augmented reality project I was working on and ended up creating ready-to-use components that you can find on my [Github](https://github.com/haf-decent/aframe-shadow-casting), in case anyone comes across this post and doesn't feel like taking the time to figure it out for themselves.